# What is the difference in using ! and % before a python command?

Tags: ipython, google-colaboratory

I know that using `!` before a command in python runs the command using the terminal.

For example:

```
!ls
!unzip zippedfile.zip
```

However, I noticed that using `%` also works for some bash commands but not for others.

So

```
%ls
```

will work, but

```
%unzip
```

will NOT work.

What is the difference between these two prefixes?

Comment: What is a "*python command*"? None of your examples here are python.

Answer (score 2):

The `!` escape runs an external shell command, like `ping -c 3 www.google.com`, not a Python command. Python or `ipython` has no idea what `ping` does, it just passes over control to it, and displays its output.

The `%` escape runs an `ipython` built-in command or extension, i.e. something that `ipython` itself understands.

To quote [the documentation](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html),

> User-extensible ‘magic’ commands. A set of commands prefixed with `%` or `%%` is available for controlling IPython itself and provides directory control, namespace information and many aliases to common system shell commands.

The source of confusion here is probably that e.g. `ls` is *also* available as a "magic" command for portability and convenience. (It's portable in that it works even on platforms where there is no system `ls` command, like Windows.)